# What is the purpose of hci_get_route()

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, bluez

Looking through code examples, it looks like `hci_get_route(NULL)` is generally used to get a device id for a Bluetooth device on the local machine. That's fine, and I can understand that. My confusion, I suppose, would only matter on a system that has more than one Bluetooth device, and where the argument to `hci_get_route()` is non-NULL. The source code for [hci.c](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/lib/hci.c) shows the following implementation:

```
int hci_get_route(bdaddr_t *bdaddr)
{
        int dev_id;

        dev_id = hci_for_each_dev(HCI_UP, __other_bdaddr,
                            (long) (bdaddr ? bdaddr : BDADDR_ANY)); 
        if (dev_id < 0)
                dev_id = hci_for_each_dev(HCI_UP, __same_bdaddr,
                                (long) (bdaddr ? bdaddr : BDADDR_ANY)); 

        return dev_id;
}
```

I won't copy the whole code of `hci_for_each_dev()`, `__other_bdaddr()`, or `__same_bdaddr()` here, but in short this function, if provided with a non-NULL `bdaddr_t*`, will try first to find a device with an address that does ***not*** match the address provided, and then, only after that fails, selects the device with the matching address. I looked back at the [commit](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/commit/4837bd7e9ba55361aeca45610a160dd107d5be2f) that introduced this function, and it's slightly different, but still uses `__other_bdaddr`:

```
int hci_get_route(bdaddr_t *bdaddr)
{
        if (bdaddr)
                return hci_for_each_dev(HCI_UP, __other_bdaddr, (long) bdaddr);
        else
                return hci_for_each_dev(HCI_UP, NULL, 0);
}
```

Even this initial version appears, very intentionally, to do the same thing, it just doesn't include the backup check using `__same_bdaddr`.

Seeing as there is no documentation for this function (that I can find), it seems that a novice user of this library would expect the `bdaddr_t*` argument to be used to select the device, so my question is, why does it do the exact opposite, preferring any other device before selecting the device with the matching address?

Comment: I would like to have a real discussion , maybe even real SOLUTION on how to retrieve necessary  parameters when start9ingt f to use local Bluetooth.I understand this forum purpose is not TO SUPPORT discussion, but provide solution.